# early flushing in java

Tags: java, performance, flush, pagespeed

In java, how can I flush content early to the browser? I think `GZipOutputStream` is buffering the content.

Are there any alternatives to `GZIPOutputStream` to `gzip`. That alternative should be able to flush content early to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

To flush content to a stream you can use flush(). Streams that don't do any buffering don't need to be flush()ed.

Do you know that your browser will do anything with files which have not been sent in full?